# Knife project not cutting through

Tags: knife-tool

I have a simple rounded edge prism. I created a circle to use as the "knife" because I want to cut 2 holes through the prism.

I first select the circle, then select the prism, go into ortho view, click tools -> knife project, to cut it:

[image]

Nothing happens after cutting it except making an extra edge in the shape of a circle:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why is nothing getting but? What do I need to do to cut THROUGH the cube?

Thanks.

Comment: A knife cuts geometry - which you must understand as adds extra edges and points. It does not cut through objects. I think what you describe you want to do is Boolean https://docs.blender.org/manual/it/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html

Answer (score 7):

After using a ***Knife Project*** tool check the ***Cut Trough*** checkbox in the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

If you place the cutting object on the 'clean' face it'll make the hole. If the cutting object is placed so it's overlaping the edges of the cuted object it'll create a geometry (edges) on it (as @lemon mentioned in his comment).
[image]

Comment: ...and that gets a wow from me :)

Comment: In fact... I don't get how you obtain that. I knew this cut through option before but here this is not making a hole, just circular cuts (added edges) for both front and back faces. How do you obtain what can be seen in your gif?

Comment: @lemon Please see my updated answer, which explains how it works (for me at least :)).

Comment: @PaulGonet, thanks for this complement to your answer. But it does not work for me, even on a simple cube (a circle to cut in plain face of a cube). I always have created edges but no hole(s). Well, this is not really a problem as I can always delete the face but this difference in the behavior is weird...

Comment: One point regarding 'cut through' in knife project is that you should use an orthographic

Comment: I'm finding it very frustrating that I am trying to do what you did with the cube - but with a cylinder. I just want to cut a shape out of a cylinder. When I use Knife Project, it selects the vertices and edges under or behind the cutting object, but it doesn't remove them.

Comment: I ran into the issue where a hole would not be made but vertices would look as they were -- it was because I was trying to cut through a hole already made