# Knife Project outlines shape but does not actually cut

Tags: knife-tool

I'm trying to use Knife Project to cut a shape in a cylinder. For now I'm testing on the cube. I've used [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7933/101310) as a guide. I added the mesh cube, then added a curve circle. I grabbed the circle and moved it up the Z axis until it was above the cube, then I scaled it so it was smaller than the cube. It's now above the cube. I hit numpad-7 to set the view. Then I select the circle, and use shift to also select the cube. I hit tab to go into the Edit Mode and then go to Mesh->Knife Project. I've tried variations on this, but it NEVER cuts through even one face of the cube. I've tilted it to a different angle for this screenshot, but it shows what I'm getting. It outlines the shape of the circle I'm using as a knife tool, but it never cuts it out.
[image]
I can press 'G' and then move the circles it makes around, or extrude them, but it never cuts through the cube, like in the answer I've linked to. I've tried using the knife tool, but that doesn't work. (Also, both the knife tool and Knife Project are only in Edit Mode, and the answer does not specify to change to the Edit Mode.) I've tried selecting the cube, going to Edit Mode and selecting the circle with ctrl-lmb. I've done the same with selecting the circle first, then selecting the cube the same way.

I've also tried, after using Knife Project and getting the circles on the cube faces to use the delete command, but none of the options delete just the circles from the cube faces. (I do have Cut Through checked on the panel that comes up for Knife Project.)

What do I need to do to make the Knife Project cut through the faces?

(Note: I've also looked over [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/knife-project-not-cutting-through) and the one answer to it, but I haven't found anything to tell me what I'm doing wrong or why I can't cut through the faces.)

Comment: The answers you found are more than 4 and 7 years old, Blender changed a lot since then. I've never used the _Knife Project_ tool much in the past, maybe they changed how it works. What do you want to achieve, to you want to have a hole where you cut the mesh or do you want the new face(s) to be separated from the rest of the mesh? After _Knife Project_, the new face(s) will be automatically selected, so to get a hole delete directly after cutting: press X > Delete> Faces. If you just want the new face(s) disconnected from the rest, simply press Y.

Comment: Both of the links relate to a very old version of Blender. You don't say what version you're using but try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnDzzHAWEHQ) quick tutorial for the later versions. You should get a dialog in the bottom left of the screen after you've done the cut which has a 'Cut through' checkbox on it.

Comment: @JohnEason He has the _Cut Through_ option clearly visible enabled in the screenshot. There is a misunderstanding on his behalf: I guess he thinks "cut through" means splitting the new edge in two separate edges so that the cut section is separated from the original mesh. And he's using 2.92.0, also visible in the screenshot.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann So he does! I guess I'm not fully awake yet! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason What time is it where you are? I've already been four hours in my office and drank loads of coffee  ;)

Comment: @Tango Just a quick explanation: "cut through" means not only the faces directly visible but also the ones that might be hidden are cut. In your screenshot, when you project top down, without "cut through" only the top face would be cut, not the bottom face. Cutting with this tool or the regular _Knife_ tool as well just means that an edge gets divided in two edges by a new vertex created at the cut or a face gets divided into two faces by a new edge where it is cut. If the mesh would automatically be split there, you might accidentally get issues with double vertices etc.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann I'm 76 next month and don't get up very early nowadays so cut me some slack! :^)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann So were you up early (or in the morning) when you were responding on my other question or, like me, up late? I'm a night person - I get more done after 10 PM than many get done all day... ;) So now the Knife Tool or Knife Project just divides the edge? That's frustrating, since it looks like, in the older versions (since those answers were older), it looks like a flat single face could be literally cut through - that would be quite helpful. I don't see a way to remove the selected part the Knife Project creates. If there were an easy way to do that, it'd help.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann As to what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to make 2 1/4" circular disks (1/4" thick) that have a pattern in them so I can convert them to STL files to make dies for a pottery extruder. (Like this one: https://www.theceramicshop.com/store/category/17/139/extruders/). I can see two ways to do that. In both I have to use a curve to create the shape of the extrusion hole. Since I'll be repeating this process, I figured the fastest way would be to make a curve, put it over the mesh for a disk, and use Knife Project to cut out the hole.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann (cont'd): The other would be to make the curve, extend it into a prism longer than the disk thickness, turn it into a mesh, then place it running through the disk and do a Boolean Modifier to cut out the shape of the prism I've made. Either way would work, but I really hate the idea of just doing the easy one and not knowing how to do the other one! This is the kind of thing I might eventually automate with an extension so I can make the curve and automate the rest. That'd make it easy to do multiple dies for experimenting with shapes for things like mug handles.

Comment: @Tango You see no way to remove the selected part the Knife Project creates? What about pressing X as I explained before...? By the way, I don't know which version they use in the old answers, I tested it now with 2.79 and there it works just like in the current version, so.... no idea. But anyway, I prefer the knives to not split or erase the geometry, Because that's easy to achieve by shortcuts X or Y. And there are many reasons to cut faces without deleting the new shape.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: I'm using 2.92.0. I realize now that those other answers are older than I thought - I saw '21' on one and assumed it was last year - didn't look closely. That was the DAY, not the year! I tried pressing X (or delete), but tried every option on the menu and didn't get what I wanted. But I'm at the point where I realize I could still be doing something small wrong. I get that there are benefits to not cutting a face, since one can extrude or do a lot of other things with the new selected area. But it would be nice if one option was to cut through.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Solution: use 'P' after doing the Knife Project. That separates the 'cut' area so I can delete it. But this creates a problem. I need a hole going all the way through the cube (or, later, my disk), and this only cuts through the two faces. It doesn't give me a tube through the disk. So it looks like, with your help, I've solved this question, but that using a Boolean Modifier does this and the next step together! If you want to write up a quick answer that pressing 'P' will separate and select the cut areas, I'll upvote and select it as the answer so you get the points.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are doing - why do you have to press P to separate it before deleting? Just hit X and choose "Faces", that deletes the selected face(s). No need for separating it beforehand. **But:** you want a tunnel, okay then do it like this: enable the _Loop Tools_ addon in the preferences. Now after _Knife Project_ with "Cut Through" option, when the cut out top and bottom face are selected, right-click and in the context menu choose _Loop Tools_ > _Bridge_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: I've tried using just X or <delete> to delete and getting results quite different than what I want, but if I use P to separate, then delete, it works as I want it to. I'll try doing that with Faces this evening. I haven't heard of Loop Tools - so that's something new I get to research and learn. I'm not being facetious when I say that I love finding new things like that! Thanks!

Comment: Are you switching to _Object Mode_ before pressing X? You have to stay in _Edit Mode_ of course.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I tried it both ways, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was something simple like that which was leading to it not working. Right now I'm creating a curve to get my shape, extruding to make it into a tube taller than the disk's thickness, then using a Boolean Modifier, and, after that, doing some beveling on the edges and it's giving me a good result. (I posted a question about the beveling, but have done a VTC on my own question - once I changed my search terms, I found another question with the answer.)